# how to avoid specific actions to call another action method MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have several action methods that get initiatated on a each Action on the page.
One of the Property asscoiated with this class has an custom-attribute defined, this inturn calls an method(action=method) defined within the same controller class.

But this action-method shouldn't be called on all actions , How to check before redirecting to this specific action ?

Answer (score 0):

You can read from filter context or controller context object the value of current action from `RouteData` like this:

```
public class MyAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var action = filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
        if(action == "xxx")
             ...// then 
        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```